# JSON to text, special sequence

Tags: json, perl, text, string-conversion

I want to create a text document from following JSON document:

```
[
    {
        "id": 12345,
        "url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "person": {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe"
        },
        "department": "IT"
    },
    {
        "id": 12346,
        "url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "person": {
            "firstname": "Anna",
            "lastname": "Jackson"
        },
        "department": "LOG"
    }
]
```

My JSON schema looks like the following:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "integer" },
            "url": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" },
            "person": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "firstname": { "type": "string" },
                    "lastname": { "type": "string" }
                }
            },
            "department": { "enum": [ "IT", "LOG"] }
        }
    }
}
```

The text document should be structured as follows:

```
pid:        12345
dep-abb:    IT
surname:    Doe
name:       John

pid:        12346
dep-abb:    LOG
surname:    Jackson
name:       Anna
```

I'm a Perl and JSON newbie and was searching for a Perl lib that can handle this approach by extending the schema (e.g. by `txt_seq_no` and `txt_label`). The labels in the text file should be sorted by `txt_seq_no` ASC and renamed by `txt_label`. Is is possible to solve that issue that simple? Then the schema could look like:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "integer", "txt_seq_no"=10, "txt_label"="pid" },
            "url": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" },
            "person": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "firstname": { "type": "string", "txt_seq_no"=40, "txt_label"="name" },
                    "lastname": { "type": "string", "txt_seq_no"=30, "txt_label"="surname" }
                }
            },
            "department": { "enum": [ "IT", "LOG", "PROD" ], "txt_seq_no"=20, "txt_label"="dep-abb" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code. If you don't have any code, then Stack Overflow is probably not the right place for your question.

Comment: You have two distinct tasks here. One is to verify your input JSON against the schema, and the other one is writing out a text file. Do you need help with both of them, or just one? Start by searching for JSON schema on CPAN. There are several implementations that should all work.

Comment: JSONSchema is only meant for validating objects, not transforming them. You could start with a function that takes one of your JSON objects and the object part of your JSONSchema and produces a new object of the form `{'10_pid': ..., '20_dep-abb': ..., ... }`. Flattening an array such objects to your desired text format should be easy then.

Comment: @simbabque I've used JSON::Validator to validate the doc against the schema (that works without any problems).

Comment: @DaveCross I really don't know how to approach to the solution of this problem...

Comment: @Botje great tip, I try that now

Comment: There is no reason to transform the data to another format when you are doing this in Perl. You can verify the JSON against the schema if you want, but there is no real need to do that. Then you convert the JSON to a Perl data structure using one of the JSON modules, iterate the array reference and build your text file from each entry. It's already nicely structured. You just need to access the data piece by piece. If you are having trouble with the indentation, `sprintf` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for tips and support!
I'm a totally beginner in Perl, feedback is welcome!
(I've ommited function parameter check to save space)

used packages:

```
use Data::Traverse;
use Data::Path;
```

sub transform

```
# key identifier[0]: mark JSON key that write into text file
# key identifier[1]: optional in JSON schema: new label in text file
my @KEY_IDENTIFIER = ("txt_seq_no", "txt_label");
# keys in JSON SCHEMA, can not be found in JSON document
my @DELETE_FROM_PATH = ( "items", "properties" );

# transform a JSON document into text file
# use identifier in JSON schema to define keys to transform to text
sub transform {
my ( $doc, $schema, $key_identifier) = @_;
if( not defined $key_identifier ) { $key_identifier = \@KEY_IDENTIFIER; }

my $transformator = get_transformator4schema( $schema, $key_identifier, $log );

my $data = get_data4transformator( $doc, $transformator, $log );

print_text( $data, $transformator, $key_identifier, $log );

}
```

sub get_transformator4schema

```
sub get_transformator4schema {
my ( $schema, $key_identifier) = @_;
my $t= Data::Traverse->new( $schema);

my %transformator;

$t->traverse(
    sub {
        if( $t->item_key eq @{$key_identifier}[0] or $t->item_key eq @{$key_identifier}[1]) {
            my $path = $t->path;
            my $key;

            # delete path that only exists in schema, not in doc
            foreach my $del_path (@DELETE_FROM_PATH) {
                $path =~ s/\/$del_path//g;
            }

            # delete last element from path
            if( $t->item_key eq @{$key_identifier}[0]) {
                $key = @{$key_identifier}[0];
                $path =~ s/\/@{$key_identifier}[0]$//g;
            }
            if( $t->item_key eq @{$key_identifier}[1]) {
                $key = @{$key_identifier}[1];
                $path =~ s/\/@{$key_identifier}[1]$//g;
            }

            # add key => { key => value }
            if( not exists $transformator{$path} ) {
                my %key_val = ( $key => $_ );
                $transformator{$path} = \%key_val;
            } else {
                my $nested_hash = $transformator{$path};
                $nested_hash->{$key} = $_;
            }
        }
    }
);
return \%transformator;
}
```

sub get_data4transformator

```
# fetch needed data from document
sub get_data4transformator {
my ( $document, $transformator, $log ) = @_;

my @template;

foreach my $doc (@{$document}) {
    my $doc_path= Data::Path->new( $doc );

    my %th = ();

    # load values for key = path
    foreach my $path (keys %{$transformator}) {
        my $val = $doc_path->get($path);
        # add value from doc to hash
        $th{$path} = $val;
    }
    push @template, \%th;
}
return \@template;
}
```

sub print_text:

```
sub print_text {

my ( $data, $transformator, $key_ids, $log ) = @_;

# sort by 1st item of $key_ids
my $sort_by = @{$key_ids}[0];
my $opt_name = @{$key_ids}[1];
print "\nsort data by '$sort_by' ASC\n";
my @sorted_keys = sort {
    $transformator->{$a}->{$sort_by}
    <=>
    $transformator->{$b}->{$sort_by}
} keys %{$transformator};

foreach my $tdoc ( @{$data} ) {
    print "\nread document item:\n";
    foreach my $key ( @sorted_keys ) {
        my $name = $key;
        $name =~ s/^.*\/(\w+)$/$1/g;
        my $alias_name = "";
        if( defined $transformator->{$key}->{$opt_name} ) {
            $alias_name = $transformator->{$key}->{$opt_name};
        }

        print   " $name => $tdoc->{$key}";
        if( not $alias_name eq "" ) {
            print " alias '$alias_name'\n";
        } else {
            print "\n";
        }
    }
}
}
```

This functionality allows to control which key goes into the text file and its position. With at least one parameter `txt_seq_no`. The second parameter `txt_label` is optional and stores the alternative label in the textfile.

output:

```
 id => 12345 alias 'pid'
 department => IT alias 'dep-abb'
 lastname => Doe
 firstname => John alias 'name'

 id => 12346 alias 'pid'
 department => LOG alias 'dep-abb'
 lastname => Jackson
 firstname => Anna alias 'name'

 id => 12347 alias 'pid'
 department => PROD alias 'dep-abb'
 lastname => Smith
 firstname => Peter alias 'name'
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is to use a [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to decode the JSON into a Perl data structure and then walk that structure to construct the output that you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;

my $json = JSON->new;

my $json_str = '[
    {
        "id": 12345,
        "url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "person": {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Doe"
        },
        "department": "IT"
    },
    {
        "id": 12346,
        "url": "https://www.w3schools.com",
        "person": {
            "firstname": "Anna",
            "lastname": "Jackson"
        },
        "department": "LOG"
    }
]';

my $data = $json->decode($json_str);

for (@$data) {
  say "pid:     $_->{id}";
  say "dep-abb: $_->{department}";
  say "surname: $_->{person}{lastname}";
  say "name:    $_->{person}{firstname}\n";
}
```